# Can xubuntu 14.04 directly be upgraded to 20.04 LTS?

Tags: xubuntu

There are similar questions already posted but they are about upgrading to relatively newer version of xubuntu but not a huge jump as in my case. I have 14.04 which is quite an old release can this be upgraded to 20.04 without reinstall ?

Thanks

Comment: No. Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: I upgraded another system from 18.04 and it directly went to 20.04 LTS. I simply followed instruction on ubuntu website, but for this one there are no instructions as such

Comment: Think it would be best to backup your data, recommended in any case and do a clean install.  Will not have to worry about upgrade causing bugs/odd behaviour.

Comment: 18.04  is supported still, 14.04 is out of support and that makes upgrades a  bit more difficult, also the more you have changed 14.04 since it came out causes problems with any upgrade.  They can't check for everything.

Comment: Release upgrades can go to the next release, OR from one LTS to to the next LTS.  18.04 could thus go to 18.10 (next release) or to 20.04 (next LTS).  From Ubuntu 14.04 your tested & fully supported upgrade paths were to 14.10 or 16.04 LTS. However Xubuntu 16.04 LTS is now EOL (3 years only is for flavors like Xubuntu, 5 for main Ubuntu) so consider a re-install (no format, using existing partitions)